# How to accept migrated answer from new account?

Tags: support, new-users, migrated-questions

I asked a question on christianity.SE, which I don't want to be associated with my account "Jan Turoň", so I didn't login to that page, just submitted a question as a new user "humanist" with the same e-mail and password as "Jan Turoň".

My question was migrated to hermeneutics.SE, where I have no account, yet I'd like to accept the answer. Where is the "humanist" account created? I tried to login with Stack Exchange, but no success.

Do I need to create another Open ID, link it with "humanist" and login with that Open ID, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Ummmm you just told everyone here that you are the same person....

Comment: Sockpuppets! Sockpuppets everywhere!

Comment: @H2CO3 That's only true if the accounts vote for each other.  Just having multiple accounts that don't interact is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Servy it may be perfectly acceptable, but they're still socks.

Comment: Sockpuppets? Just a pseudonym, it is not a secret. At least not for meta people ;-) No reason to keep it secret: 100% people don't care, I'm not a movie star.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have two sets of accounts that are linked across sites, then you will need two OpenIDs. So you will need to create an OpenID for the "humanist" account on Christianity and then log into Hermeneutics with that same OpenID. This should find the question and link it to your account.

This is fine and is a system used by quite a few others.

Sockpuppetry doesn't come into it as you are not using the second account on Stack Overflow.